# "Invalid JSON Number" Spring Data Mongo 2.0.2

Tags: json, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

** FIXED **
All I had to do is add an apostrophe before and after each argument index,

i.e, change:

`@Query(value = "{'type': 'Application','name': ?0,'organizationId': ?1}", fields = "{_id:1}")`

To:

```
@Query(value = "{'type': 'Application','name': '?0','organizationId': '?1'}", fields = "{_id:1}")
```

===================

I recently upgraded my MongoDB and my Spring-Data-MongoDB Driver.

I used to access my MongoDB through mongoRepository using this code:

```
@Query(value = "{'type': 'Application','name': ?0,'organizationId': ?1}", fields = "{_id:1}")
Policies findPolicyByNameAndOrganizationId(String name, String organizationId);
```

Where Policies is the object I want to consume.

After performing an update to Spring, I get the following Error now when accessing the method above:

> org.bson.json.JsonParseException: Invalid JSON number

I fear this is because I use Spring's MongoCoverter (in the case of this specific object only) to map documents to object.

Here's is my Reader Converter:

```
public class ApplicationPolicyReadConverotor implements Converter<Document, ApplicationPolicy > {
private MongoConverter mongoConverter;

public ApplicationPolicyReadConverotor(MongoConverter mongoConverter) {
    this.mongoConverter = mongoConverter;
}

//@Override
public ApplicationPolicy convert(Document source) {
    ApplicationPolicyEntity entity = mongoConverter.read(ApplicationPolicyEntity.class, source);
    ApplicationPolicy policy = new ApplicationPolicy();
    addFields(policy, entity);
    addPackages(policy, entity);
    return policy;
}
```

And here's is my Writer Converter:

```
public class ApplicationPolicyWriteConvertor implements Converter<ApplicationPolicy, Document>{

private MongoConverter mongoConverter;

public ApplicationPolicyWriteConvertor(MongoConverter mongoConverter) {
    this.mongoConverter = mongoConverter;
}

@Override
public Document convert(ApplicationPolicy source) {
    System.out.println("mashuWrite");
    ApplicationPolicyEntity target = new ApplicationPolicyEntity();
    copyFields(source, target);
    copyPackages(source, target);
    Document Doc = new Document();
    mongoConverter.write(target,  Doc);
    return Doc;
}
```

I [checked Spring reference (2.0.2) regarding MongoConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.custom-converters) and how it works and at this stage I think I'm doing it correctly.

Other object who do not use mapping/conversions suffer no problems. 
Same did this Object (ApplicationPolicy) untill I upgraded my mongo and my spring driver.

My mongodb is 3.4.10 and Spring data mongo driver is 2.0.2.

Here's the code that initializes the MappingMongoCoverter Object:
(Adds my custom Converters).

```
SimpleMongoDbFactory simpleMongoDbFactory = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(client, dbName);
    DefaultDbRefResolver defaultDbRefResolver = new DefaultDbRefResolver(simpleMongoDbFactory);
    MongoMappingContext mongoMappingContext = new MongoMappingContext();
    MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter = new MappingMongoConverter(defaultDbRefResolver,
            mongoMappingContext);
    mappingMongoConverter.setMapKeyDotReplacement("_dot_");
    // Adding custom read and write converters for permission policy.
    mappingMongoConverter.setCustomConversions(new MongoCustomConversions(Arrays.asList(
            new ApplicationPolicyWriteConvertor(mappingMongoConverter), new ApplicationPolicyReadConverotor(
                    mappingMongoConverter))));
    mappingMongoConverter.afterPropertiesSet();
    final MongoTemplate template = new MongoTemplate(simpleMongoDbFactory, mappingMongoConverter);
    return template;
```

I know for sure that ReaderConverter WORKS legit (at least in some cases) since other aspects of the software use the custom ReaderConverter I've written and it works as expected.

Also when using debug mode (Intellij) I do not reach to the conversion code block when invoking the following:

> ```
> @Query(value = "{'type': 'Application','name': ?0,'organizationId': ?1}", fields = "{_id:1}")
> Policies findPolicyByNameAndOrganizationId(String name, String organizationId);
> ```

So basically I'm kinda clueless. I have a sense my converter Implementation is messy but couldn't fix it..

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace where you're getting the `JsonParseException`?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, the issue has been fixed and I edited the original Post.